# If $r$ indistinguishable objects are placed at random in $n(>r) $ cells, hat $(n-r)$ cells are left empty just one after another?

Tags: combinatorics

If $r$ indistinguishable objects are placed at random in $n(>r) $ cells, find the probability that $(n-r)$ cells are left empty just one after another?

Comment: How many objects can be placed in a cell? Should it be a single sequence of exactly (n−r) empty cells or a single sequence of at least (n−r) cells or at least one sequence of exactly (n−r) empty cells or at least one sequence of at least (n−r) cells?